# On Facebook, can I find out who else likes a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I can see that 103 people "like" a page but how can I find out who they are?

With the old "group" system this was so easy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list is only available to page admins. You can only see which of your friends liked the it.